# How can I query a firestore database and get the results sorted by a specific timestamp field

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following function that I want to use to query my Firestore database and sort the posts by date posted. here's my code so far (not working) I get the posts back, but they are not sorted by the timestamp with the most recent on top.

My database looks like this:

```
{
   postText: "No longer stale posts?"
   postTime: February 3, 2021 at 1:32:35 AM UTC-8
   userId: "DsZoqkPhbshXsOKOpkcsW3Vh5313"
}
```

My code:

```
export const getWhere = async (collection, doc, field) => {
    const snapshot = await db
        .collection(collection)
        .where(field, '==', doc) // where("userId" == "currentUserId")
        .limit(20)
        .orderBy('postTime', 'asc') // "postTime" is a timestamp field.
        .get()
        .then(function (querySnapshot) {
            const final = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
                final.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
            });
            return final;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
        });
    return snapshot;
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show: 1) a screenshot of a document with the `postTime` field visible? 2) a `console.log` of the `postTime` values inside your `querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {` code block? For this please show the updated code, and its output.

Comment: like Frank said, check/log your `timeSatmp` field. And another note, to get most recent at top, `postTime` should be in desc order like - `orderBy('postTime', 'desc')`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. It seems like I had a brainfart and had the `'asc'` order set when it should have been `'desc'`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by simply changing the order from `asc` to `desc`. Not sure why it initially was showing up in the order that they were stored in the database. Hope this helps someone, there was a need to create an index for this in firestore's indexes section:

`posts userId Ascending postTime Descending Collection`

```
export const getWhere = async (collection, doc, field) => {
    const snapshot = await db
        .collection(collection)
        .where(field, '==', doc)
        .limit(20)
        .orderBy('postTime', 'desc')
        .get()
        .then(function (querySnapshot) {
            const final = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
                final.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
            });
            return final;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
        });
    return snapshot;
}
```